# Two outlook mail accounts with only 1 sender address

Tags: outlook

The users are receiving mails from 2 accounts but are supposed to send and reply only from one mail account, disregarding on what account the mail was received on.

The sender account is tagged as primary and the check mark in the sending options is already set "*use primary account as standard sending address*"

It works for creating a new mail too, but not when the mail is forwarded or replied on the other account.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, this is by design, you need to change the "from" field manually when reply or forward messages in another account in outlook. As below:
[image]